Change Ocaml default repl
I am using Ocaml with emacs. I've configured emacs using opam user-setup install. I'm using the repl a lot and it seems that the default one is utop (When I use C-x C-e or C-c C-a).
I want to use the ocaml traditional repl and the only way to access it is by using C-M-x which is linked to the same command as C-x C-e (tuareg-eval-phrase). I don't understand how two different shortcuts which execute the same command can call two different repls.
I would like to know how to put ocaml as my default repl
